# Partial Match Select an element in dropdown c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have page with lots of dropdowns and I seem to have a problem in writing something generic rather than hardcoding the full path.

The idea is to locate the country dropdown and selecting an item from the dropdown

**THIS WORKS**

```
 public MyPage WithCountry(string countryValue)
 {
    driver
    .FindElement(By.CssSelector("#ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ApplicantDetails1_Panel_ctl00_ctl03_CountryList > span.ui-selectmenu-text"))
    .Click();

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ui-id-162")).Click();
    return this;
}
```

**This does not work**

```
 public MyPage WithCountry(string countryValue)
 {   
    var element=driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector( "[Id$=ctl03_CountryList]");  
    element(By.CssSelector("# > span.ui-selectmenu-text")).Click();  //NOT SURE ABOUT THIS GIVES ME ERROR.
    driver.FindElement(By.Name(countryValue)).Click();
    return this;
}
```

html

```
    <ul id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucApplicantDetails1_ApplicantPanel_ctl00_ctl03_CountryList" class="form-columns">
    <li class="large-4 columns">
            <label for="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucApplicantDetails1_ApplicantPanel_ctl00_ctl03CountryListList" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucApplicantDetails1_ApplicantPanel_ctl00_ctl03_CountryListLblFor">CountryList&nbsp;
                <span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
    </li>
    <li class="hidden">
            <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucApplicantDetails1_ApplicantPanel_ctl00_ctl03_CountryListReqVal" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="large-12 columns">
        <select name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceholder$ucApplicantDetails1$ApplicantPanel$ctl00$ctl03$CountryList" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucApplicantDetails1_ApplicantPanel_ctl00_ctl03_CountryList" class="xxx">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
```

Can anybody give any suggestions how I should code this method so that an element in the drop down is selected,by finding the element by partial match

Comment: show `HTML` code for same

Comment: added  html that concerns this drop down

Comment: What do you mean partial match actually?? Do you want to select option from dropdown with partial match text??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I mean Find the dropdown (element) by partial match rather than the long generated name just find the element by matching on the end like i did but does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the built-in `SelectElement` class?

For example I created some extension wrapper methods for it like:

```
public static void SelectElementByName(this IWebElement selectDropDown, string valueToSelect)
{
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(selectDropDown);
    if (selectElement.SelectedOption.Text == valueToSelect)
    {
        return;
    }
    selectElement.SelectByText(valueToSelect);
}
```

Usage:

```
var countrySelectElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("css_selector_here"));
countrySelectElement.SelectElementByName("Spain");
```

Then, also using `SelectElement` class you could get your currently selected element, all the options from the drop-down, etc.
Have a look at the github repo for this: [SelectElement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs)

Comment: thanks for your reply few things                                              1) my cssselector finds nothing [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[Id$=CountryList]")]
        [CacheLookup]
        private IWebElement country;  I get error "Message = "Element should have been select but was ul"                                                       2)Not sure what the CSSSelector should be that is my main problem ,this is the place where i want to partial match . Hope all clear .Any ideas

Comment: The error message is pretty much self explanatory. You have multiple items matching `"[Id$=CountryList]"`, the first one being the unordered list (`ul` tag). From the html snippet posted by you, you have 4 elements that have their id containing `CountryList`. 
However if you're using the extension method that I gave you, you only need to find whatever individual SelectTag you need and select the value desired from drop-down.

Also, I'm not sure what multiple elements you want to identify using the `CssSelector` provided by you.

Comment: hi i have used the extension method you provided and did not work.Surely I might be using wrongly.In my little knowledge of Selenium I do "find me an element that has an Id that ends with "countryList" [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[Id$=CountryList]")] [CacheLookup] private IWebElement countryList .look at "Id$" this i thought it would find the element and  then call your method like this        countryList .SelectElementByName("Spain");

Comment: Your assumption is partially correct.  The full explanation would be "find me the first element that has an Id that ends with `countryList`". The problem is, as I mentioned in my previous comment, is that `countryList` matches multiple elements, the first one being an `ul` tag. `SelectElement` class is expecting a `select` tag and your `select` tag is the last element that matches `countryList`. An easier way to do it would be using xpath like this: `[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//select[contains(@id,'CountryList')]")] [CacheLookup] private IWebElement country;`

Comment: first thanks for your time and help,what you are saying makes sense,Still does not work but will look into it.thanks